# How to config PSR coding standards in Sublime Text2 for PHP

Tags: sublimetext2

I have installed Sublime Text2. I want auto formatting php code to PSR Standards. Can anyone please help me how to configure in Sublime Text2

Answer (score 2):

I just yesterday installed one plugin that you could use for PSR-1 and PSR-2.

Link that I found for this is:

[sublimetext-codeformatter](https://github.com/akalongman/sublimetext-codeformatter)

Install it in Sublime Text 3 via console and after that you can use from `Command Pallete` [CTRL + P windows (default keyboard shortcut)] and type `format` and choose `Codeformatter: Format code` and this will format your code. You can see also the options for PHP and adapt them as you want, see 2nd image.

[image]

---

[image]

---

Default PHP settings:
[image]

---

I also adjusted my own keyboard shortcut in `Preferences -> Keybindings`

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+l"], "command": "code_formatter"}
```

**If you need something more, tag me below in comments and I'll gladly reply back.**

Answer (score 1):

I believe that to achive what you are looking for, there are several steps included:

1) Download and install [Sublime PHPCS](http://benmatselby.github.io/sublime-phpcs/)

2) Configure according php packages you intend to use (Available: PHP_CodeSniffer, PHP Mess Detector, PHP CS Fixer, Scheck and PHP Code Beautifier)

3) Lastly you will need to configure the plugin inside of sublime text.

According to this [link](http://neverstopbuilding.com/sublime-plugins-for-php) here, you can configure it to comply with PSR-2 standard.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will check.